# One to Many Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have created a database with One to many relationship

The Parent Table say Master has 2 columns NodeId,NodeName; NodeId is the PrimaryKey and it is of type int rest are of type varchar.

The Child Table say Student has 5 columns NodeId,B,M,F,T; and NodeId is the ForeignKey over here.

none of the columns B,M,F,T are unique and it can have null values hence none of these columns have been defined as Primary Key.

assume student table has more than 20,00,000 fields.

My fetch query is

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE NODEID = 1 AND B='1-123'
```

I would like to improve the speed of fetching , Any suggestion regarding improvement of the DB structure or alternative fetch query would be really helpful or any suggestion that can improve overall efficiency is most welcome.

Comment: Do you have an index on `Student.NodeID`?

Comment: No I havent defined an Index on Student.NodeId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since foreign key is not indexed by default, maybe adding indexes to nodeID in student and B would improve query performance if inserts performance are not as big of a issue.

Update:

an index is essentially a way to keep your data sorted to increase search/query time. It should be good enough to just think of it as an ordered list.

An index is quite transparent, so your query would remain exactly the same.

A simple index does allow rows with the same indexed fields, so it should be fine.
it is worth to m mention. a primary key element is indexed by default, however a PK does not allow duplicate data.

also, since it's keeping an ordering of your data, insertion time will increase, however if your dataset is big query time should become faster.

Comment: I'm not clear with the concept of indexing, hence I have a few queries wrt to my table: 1) From what I know, there is Create Index statement that is used to create the index and we have to provide an index name along with it, So will my Select query have to be changed or can i use the same as i had mentioned earlier. 2) The table will be updated often as in new fields will be added and many fields will be deleted will that affect indexing in any way. 3) If there are multiple fields with same NodeId and B value is it an issue?

Comment: since its quite wordy i will edit my original post to answer these questions.